# Delphi 2006 - msxml: What version of msxml does the vcl consume?

Tags: delphi

Specifically, if msxml 4 is not present on the system, and msxml 6 is present, will the Delphi msxml component (in Delphi 2006) use msxml 6?

Comment: Q: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @paulsm4 The Delphi component seems to be compatible with more than one msxml version, but it is unclear how it behaves (esp as there is often, but not always, more than one msxml version on a system)

Comment: There's no "one right answer": to the extent that `TXmlDocument `relies on the COM runtime for MSXML ... the behavior might be different from PC to PC.  Read the [link](https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/03/07/using-msxml6/) below.  One other variable I forgot to mention: you can explicitly register/unregister and set [DOMVendor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument.DOMVendor) in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Why don't you try it?

I presume you mean the Delphi class [TXmlDocument](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_TXMLDocument) and friends.  It "expects" MSXML 4 ... but the VCL checks dynamically:

> https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/03/07/using-msxml6/
>
> By default, the VCL’s TXMLDocument class will delegate to MSXML for
>   its actual parsing and writing. Now MSXML itself comes in various
>   versions, with newer ones being installed side-by-side with older
>   ones. To cope with this situation, the VCL tests for the existence of
>   a number of them, the idea being to prefer whatever MSXML version was
>   current when the unit in question (MSXMLDOM.pas) was last updated.

The same link also discusses how to select a "preferred" MSXML version if you wish.

STRONG SUGGESTION: Compile your Delphi .exe or .dll and test it on a "clean machine" (presumably a PC with only MSXML 6 installed) and observe the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to test on a machine with only msxml6, because even Windows10 installs out of box with msxml3 and msxml6 present.